# How to get the root class object in stream loop

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-stream

I have a 3 classes . I need the PostProcessorRequest if  vifLineItemResponse.isSuccess() is true . How i can get the PostProcessorRequest if condition is true in its one nested field class .

```
public class PostProcessorRequest {
    FulfillmentResponse response;
    SalesOrderDocument orderDocument;
    //Getters and setters 
}

public class FulfillmentResponse {
    Collection<VifLineItemResponse> responses;
    //Getters and setters 
}

public class VifLineItemResponse {
    VifLineItem vifLineItem;
    boolean isSuccess;
    // Getters and setters 
}
```

The way i have tried is

```
postProcessorRequest.getResponse()
                    .getResponses()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(match -> match.isSuccess())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But i am getting `FulfillmentResponse` object only . How i can get the `postProcessorRequest`?

Comment: OK i tweaked the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite clear if you need to check whether at least one response is successful, or whether they all are successful, but either way, you probably want to use Optional on the root object instead of streaming the leaf objects:

```
Optional.of(postProcessorRequest)
        .filter(ppr->ppr.response!=null)
        .filter(ppr->ppr.response.responses.stream().anyMatch(VifLineItemResponse::isSuccess))
        .ifPresent(ppr-> {
            // ppr has at least one success response,
            // do with it whatever needs to be done
        })
```

If you need all responses to be true, change `anyMatch` to `allMatch`

Or, you could change your classes to have a bi-directional relationship, i.e. something like this:

```
public class PostProcessorRequest {
    FulfillmentResponse response;
    SalesOrderDocument orderDocument;
    //Getters and setters 
}

public class FulfillmentResponse {
    Collection<VifLineItemResponse> responses;
    PostProcessorRequest getRequest(){ /* points back to parent */ }
    //Getters and setters 
}

public class VifLineItemResponse {
    VifLineItem vifLineItem;
    PostProcessorRequest getFulfillmentResponse(){ /* points back to parent */ }
    boolean isSuccess;
    // Getters and setters 
}
```

Now we can adapt your original code:

```
postProcessorRequest.getResponse()
                    .getResponses()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(match -> match.isSuccess())
                    .map(VifLineItemResponse::getFulfillmentResponse)
                    .map(FulfillmentResponse::getRequest)
                    .distinct()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: ifPresent(ppr-> {

            // Whether this ppr object is the only object satisfied the  isSuccess condition ?
        })                                                                                                                                 Actually i need the postProcessorRequest which subclass satisfied the condition . I think now its giving all the postProcessorRequest objects